# iPad overlaying text onto a pdf document

Tags: ipad, text, draw

I have a pdf and I'd like to be able to allow users to write on top of it (to sign a signature) in the middle of my iPad app, and then save the pdf with their signature.

What is the best way to do it? I'm sure there exists something already to do this. It seems unnecessary to rewrite the code to make this work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by drawing text into the pdf context using core graphics functions. A code snippet to help this:

```
//Assuming this code inside a context

CGAffineTransform textTransform = CGAffineTransformMake(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
CGContextSetTextMatrix(context, textTransform);
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [UIColor blackColor].CGColor);
CGContextSelectFont(context,fontName, fontSize, kCGEncodingMacRoman);
CGContextSetTextDrawingMode(context, kCGTextFill);

const char *st = [@"Sample Text" cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

CGContextShowTextAtPoint(context, 100.0, 100.0, st, [@"Sample Text" length]);
```